# Query *only* sticky posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, sticky-post

I've been using the following query to try to output *only* posts that are marked as stickies:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')
    );
?>

<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php get_template_part('loop', 'feed-top-stories' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I currently have no posts set as stickies on the website. Which tells me that nothing should show up in the loop. However, I found that it was pulling in 2 posts anyway (even though they weren't stickies)

So then I switched to a WP_Query object (as I was advised to avoid `query_posts()` in the past)

```
<?php

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'posts_per_page' => 2
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        get_template_part('loop', 'feed-top-stories' );

    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

But now it doesn't appear to be working at all, the loop seems to be outputting 2 posts, however both of them are the page that is being viewed, despite me setting the `post_type` parameter

Comment: @PieterGoosen that doesn't appear to fix my problem... although I don't see how ignoring the sticky posts would?

Comment: Sticky posts are automatically appended to the query, so I could see why Pieter would suggest ignoring them, since you're also explicitly querying sticky posts. I suggest looking at `$the_query->request` after it is run to see the SQL being generated, it's possible you have some incorrectly targeted filter interfering.

Comment: @Milo ah I see! Thanks. I've tried that and, although I'm no SQL expert, I'd say the request doesn't bear much resemblance to the query that I'm trying to make? (I'll post below this comment)

Comment: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 2`

Answer (score 16):

> I currently have no posts set as stickies on the website. Which tells me that nothing should show up in the loop.

Exactly where you are wrong when passing an empty array to `post__in`. WordPress has some silly bugs which has no proper workaround and will most probably stay active bugs for a very long time. This is one of them.

When we pass a valid array of posts ID's to `post__in`, we get the following resultant SQL `WHERE` clause (***NOTE:*** All test are done on a page)

```
AND wp_posts.ID IN (59,45) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = \'post\' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = \'publish\' OR wp_posts.post_status = \'private\')
```

Now, if we have no stickies, thus passing an empty array to `post__in`, the following SQL is wrongly generated because the `post__in` parameter as seen as not set.

```
AND wp_posts.ID IN (59) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = \'post\' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = \'publish\' OR wp_posts.post_status = \'private\')
```

This is an epic fail with unexpected output. Depending on the parameters you passed you get totally unrelated posts or no posts at all.

That is why you should always validate what you are passing to `post__in` if the passed values are a dynamic array to avoid this epic failure.

Just another note which might not make any sense at all, if you just need to query sticky posts, always set `ignore_sticky_posts` to `1` (*true*). The reason for this is, should you require to not query all the sticky posts or just stickies from a certain category, you get just the ones you need. If you do not ignore stickies, all stickies will be returned regardless of what you have queried (*yet another silly bug in my opinion*).

You can rewrite your code as follow

```
$stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
// Make sure we have stickies to avoid unexpected output
if ( $stickies ) {
    $args = [
        'post_type'           => 'post',
        'post__in'            => $stickies,
        'posts_per_page'      => 2,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    ];
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
            $the_query->the_post();

            get_template_part('loop', 'feed-top-stories' );

        }    
        wp_reset_postdata();    
    }
}
```

Comment: "Just another note which might not make any sense at all, if you just need to query sticky posts, always set ignore_sticky_posts to 1 (true). The reason for this is, should you require to not query all the sticky posts or just stickies from a certain category, you get just the ones you need. If you do not ignore stickies, all stickies will be returned regardless of what you have queried (yet another silly bug in my opinion)."

And even if you do this, the `post__not_in` becomes useless nevertheless.

Comment: Wow, this is super helpful. Thanks! My query was for showing sticky posts at the top of each category’s posts and it seemed to be working fine until I ran into the case where there were zero sticky posts across the entire site. Your suggestion to use a conditional for `get_option( 'sticky_posts’ )` was just what I needed.